# C++: Sort list alphabetically, display only first and last items

Tags: c++, sorting

**Update**: Final versions, [with `<set>`](http://pastie.org/8396380) and [without `<set>`](http://pastie.org/8396372).

I've been working on a problem:

> Design a program that asks the user for a series of names (in no
>   particular order). After the final person’s name has been entered, the
>   program should display the name that is first alphabetically and the
>   name that is last alphabetically.
>
> For example, if the user enters the names Kristin, Joel, Adam, Beth,
>   Zeb, and Chris, the program would display Adam and Zeb.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void displayOutput(const string& item)
{
    cout << item << endl;
}

int main()
{
    set<string> sortNames;
    string name;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a name (\"end\" to finish):\t";
        cin >> name;

        sortNames.insert(name);
    } while ( name != "end" );

    for_each(sortNames.begin(), sortNames.end(), &displayOutput);

    return 0;
}
```

My code so far works fine, in that it displays all inputted strings alphabetically. (On a side note, I'm not sure how to get around having "end" not display in the output itself.) The problem is, the program is only supposed to display the (alphabetically) *first and last names* from the list. I've been thinking about it, and I think that I might have to approach the problem from a different angle, but I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given the way you have done it, instead of `for_each()`, just call `displayOutput()` twice, once on `begin()` and once on `rbegin()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for_each(sortNames.begin(), sortNames.end(), &displayOutput);` goes through the entire set, and for each item, calls its `displayOutput` member function.

You apparently only want to call the `displayOutput` on the first item, `sortNames.begin()` and the last, `sortNames.rbegin()`.

Sorry, but since this is apparently homework, I'm not going to give a more explicit answer than that.

As for avoiding `end` being shown (and being part of the collection), you have a basic problem with logic. Right now, you read a name, add it to the collection, *then* check if it's `end`, and if so quit adding more names. What you probably want to do is read a name, check if it's end, and only add it to the collection if it's not (then break out of the loop if it is).

I'd probably rewrite the code something like this:

```
std::string getname() { 
    string name;

    cout << "Enter a name (\"end\" to finish):\t";
    cin >> name;
    return name;
}

int main() {
   std::set<std::string> sortNames;
   std::string name;

   while ((name=getname()) != "end")
       sortNames.insert(name);
   // ...
}
```

I'd also note that there's really no need to store all the names in a set. You could just store two strings, one that's that's the first alphabetically among those seen so far, and one that's the last. When you read each string, check whether it's less than the first (and if so, save it as the first). Otherwise, check if it's greater than the last (and if so, save it as the last).

Comment: Thanks. It *is* for a class, a question that I've been working on, trying to understand, but is not necessarily homework.

Comment: @shawnj: Okay -- but still close enough to the same thing (at least from my perspective).

Comment: I definitely appreciate it. I wouldn't be learning if I was given the answer. I'll try to figure this out. Part I'm not sure on is where I'm supposed to "call `displayOutput` *on* `sortNames.begin()`." I know this is basic, but if I'm not using `for_each()`, then how do I go about it? I tried something like `sortNames.begin(&displayOutput)` but I know that's not quite right.

Comment: @shawnj: `sortNames.begin()` returns an iterator, which acts like a pointer, so you want to dereference the point, then call `displayOutput` on the result. The pointer-to operator (`->`) is a handy shortcut for dereferencing a pointer, then referring to a member of the result.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I've tried several different ways. I'm unsure of the syntax necessary to pass the result to the display function. For example, I've tried this: `sortNames.begin() -> displayOutput();`, but I get the error that no member named `displayOutput` exists, so I'm guessing I've got something backwards or missing a piece.

Comment: @shawnj: Sorry -- looking at things again, I messed up. I somehow thought `displayOutput` was a member function, but it's actually a global function that you'd pass the the object pointed to by the iterator it, so it would be something like `displayOutput(*sortNames.begin());`.